# Z values all equal 0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

I have a point layer, and have got the x,y and z coordinates from 'extract values to points'. The x and y values appear fine in the attribute table but the z values are all 0. I have about 150 points, so I do not particularly want to go through each by way of info point!

Can anyone provide some advice on how to get the true z values?

I have posted a question previous to this one which is similar [Extracting Z data from point layer using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/how-to-extract-z-data-from-a-point-layer/98245#98245)

Slightly different as I can now retrieve and  X and Y, but Z is still a mystery.

Comment: It is a problem stemmed from that question. But I feel this is a different problem. I now have z co-ordinates but they are just all 0.

Comment: Try adding a new field and populating it with Z values to determine if the feature dataset actually has them and they are non-zero.

Comment: No, It has also given values of 0. Surely there is a way to get the z values easily from the DEM?!

Comment: Are the coordinate systems the same between the points and DEM, or did Arc project-on-the-fly?

Comment: If you are trying to get a similar Question to another answered, then to avoid getting it closed as a Duplicate, I recommend always providing a link to the original, and editing your new Question to explain precisely why you think it is not a duplicate.  Also, make sure to "finish off" the original Q&A by making sure that you revise its Question to be just the part resolved and Accept-ing an Answer.

Comment: @Aaron, the co-ordinate systems are the same. Thanks PolyGeo, I shall do that in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

@Katie C, as I described in your other question, you can do the following:

"I have never had an issue with this process. An alternative is to use GME (Geospatial Modeling Environment) spatialecology.com/gme and use the isectpntrst tool"

GME is a free download. I do this process every week, so I know it works. This process will take a point layer and extract the value from a DEM and save it to the attribute table.

Here is a link to the explanation from the website: http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/isectpntrst.htm

Comment: Hi Ryan, because I am on a university computer I do not have the admin rights to download the GME. Unfortunately it takes a long time to try and retrieve these passwords, hence I need to find a solution that involves only the tools in ArcGIS.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. I have never tried this, but you could look at doing Zonal Statistics to Table, which is in Toolbox --> Spatial Analyst. I have successfully used it with polygons, but not points. If this does not work for a point file, you could buffer the points to a small distance (ie: 0.05m) and then run the process on the buffered points.